# i had this error in my below java code (unreachable return statement & missing return statement)

Tags: java

```
package oopTest;
public class Chhapgar {
    public String chap(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                String y = String.valueOf(i);
                return y;
                break ;
            default :
                String nist = "nist";
                return nist;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The last `break;` statement is unreachable, your method will have returned before .

Comment: Does the title contain the literally and fully quoted single error message? Or are there actually two or more error messages? Please quote all of them, separatly, literally, completely and within the question body, where more space and formatting is available.

Comment: @Arnaud Both breaks are unreachable, but none of the returns.

Comment: Can we see the exact error message? Both return statements are reachable. Neither break statements are reachable.